# Bash sleep function

Tags: bash, suspend

With the bash sleep function, can you program sleep in a bash script to sleep 5 seconds, then 500 seconds then 1000 and rotate to back to 5,500,1000? Thanks, my current script below.

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool

``
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
  xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 1 &
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: As a simple solution, you can put the three `sleep` statements one after another, and then all of them into a loop.

Comment: Technically, bash does not have a "sleep function". [`sleep`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/sleep.1.html) is a separate executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep` is an external command - not a bash function.

To cycle indefinitely through a set of values, you can use an array with an index derived using modulo arithmetic. Ex.

```
#!/bin/bash

s=(5 500 1000)

i=0
while : ; do
  # some commands
  sleep "${s[i]}"
  i=$((++i%3))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you would want to do this, but

```bsh
for rotations in 1 2; do
  for duration in 5 500 1000; do
    sleep $duration
  done
done
```